# Chinese Idiom puzzle 15 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

A new puzzle for Feb 2021

[image]

1. It’s better to see it with your own eyes than hear it hundreds of times.
2. It often takes many twists and turns to get what you want
3. Good for others and oneself
4. Boxing
5. Never forget after reading it, having a strong memory
6. Therefore
7. Debate
8. Prosthetic limb
9. Can only choose one between two good things
10. Another name for 蜈蚣 (Centipede)
11. Want to cry but no tear. A metaphor of extreme grief or helplessness
12. Move in a manner like a dragon and a tiger. A metaphor of majestic mannerism
13. 春秋時代法家代表人物。齊國的政治家，哲學家，與樂毅齊名
14. Willing to do good, like to give charity
15. One and only
16. Permit
17. (Cantonese saying) Describe a person suddenly becoming clear-minded upon listening to a word of wisdom
18. Accidentally missed or misunderstood; an unforeseeable, coincidental turn of even
19. Treat someone wronged you with kindness
20. Describe the light is very bright at night
21. Catalog; table of contents
22. Give help when it is needed the most
23. 李煜 (The last monarch of the Southern Tang Dynasty)
24. Deep grudges
25. People with superb skills tend to be bold.
26. Busy running around
27. A lot of people came to the door, it was as lively as a vegetable market

A. Can't defend a charge, no matter what you say

B.  '只許州官放火' 下句 (double standard)

C. Gardening

D. Give rewards based on merit

E. 祝融

F. Know nothing

G. Archery technique or marksmanship is very accurate

H. brazenly, openly

I. Having a scare but unscathed

J. Seeing profit and disregarding morality

K. Orchestral

L. Looking for and pursuing even in dreams. Describe strong desire

M. Sharp

N. Another name for 醫生 Doctor

O. Don't do things to people that you don't want people to do to you

P. Take revenge

Q. Secretly fawn

R. Crocodile tears

S. Order/ Dispatch someone to do something somewhere;

T. Fact

U. Lonely

V. Unruly child  (Internet term)

W. One mistake after another

X. Having a large number of students (including former students)

Y. Metaphor of preparing for action or using force

Z. There is only one sun in the sky; there is only one ruler for the people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 百闻不如一见
2. 好事多磨
3. 利人利己
4. 拳击
5. 过目不忘
6. 所以
7. 辩论
8. 义肢
9. 鱼与熊掌
10. 百足
11. 欲哭无泪
12. 龙行虎步
13. 管仲
14. 乐善好施
15. 独一无二
16. 许可
17. 一语惊醒梦中人
18. 阴差阳错
19. 以德报怨
20. 灯火通明
21. 目录
22. 雪中送炭
23. 李后主
24. 深仇大恨
25. 艺高人胆大
26. 奔波
27. 门庭若市

A. 百辞莫辩

B. 不许百姓点灯

C. 园艺

D. 论功行赏

E. 火神

F. 一窍不通

G. 百步穿杨

H. 明目张胆

I. 有惊无险

J. 见利忘义

K. 管弦乐

L. 梦寐以求

M. 锋利

N. 大夫

O. 己所不欲，勿施于人

P. 报仇雪恨

Q. 暗送秋波

R. 鳄鱼泪

S. 差遣

T. 事实

U. 孤独

V. 熊孩子

W. 一错再错

X. 桃李满庭

Y. 磨拳擦掌

Z. 天无二日，民无二主